# display this when right click on an image

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to create a website to display each product with an image, but I want to disable it to users to **download** the image's product when the user right-click on it, he/she can't to download it or Open the image on new tab to download, I read many questions on StackOverflow about it but nothing tells me how to do it. I want to display **this box** which on the below image appears.
[image]

please help me.

Comment: Are you saying there is nowhere on the www on how to have an event handler on right click?

Comment: This was a popular request in the 90s/early 2000s. PHP is not related to this. This also is not a secure. If you dont want the user being able to get the image dont share it with them. Everything else is security by obscurity. Here's a tutorial that looks like it is from early 2000s and has code on it that still works http://www.pagetutor.com/no_right_click/.

Comment: @GetSet I Know if you have a knowledge technical experience you can disable js and download the image but I do it to prevent. I don't know which is the best way to do it.  If you know good way please tell me.

Comment: @user3783243 thanks. I read it but I don't know which is the correct way to do it. please tell me if u know...

Comment: @LanDanel checkout my code it works even if the user has already disabled JS, because only HTML and CSS are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cover your image like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <title>some title</title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .img-container {
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .img-container img, .img-container .img-cover {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .img-container .img-cover {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="your_image.png">
    <div class="img-cover"></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```